# Prove that : $x^n+4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Prove that : $x^n+4$ is irreducible  on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if only if $n\neq 4k$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $x^8+4$ is reducible: $x^8+4=(x^4-2x^2+2)(x^4+2x^2+2)$ but $8 \not =4^k$.

Comment: Perhps you meant $4k$ rather than $4^k$?

Comment: $4k$ is that true.I sorry all.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133581/when-is-xn-a-is-irreducible-over-f