# How many non-rational complex numbers $x$ have the property that $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are rational?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069786/a-real-number-x-such-that-xn-and-x1n-are-rational-is-itself-rational/1070404#1070404), I proved the following statement:

> *For each positive integer $n$, there are finitely many non-rational complex numbers $x$ such that $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are rational. These complex numbers all have the form $$x(a,b)=\frac{\zeta^b-\zeta^a}{1- \zeta^b},$$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and $a,b$ are different nonzero elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.*

However, a search with a computer suggests that there are even finitely many such complex numbers over all $n$. I have counted $26$ of them.

Let $S_n$ be the set of non-rational complex numbers such that $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are rational. Since $x^{nm}$ and $(x+1)^{mn}$ are rational if $x^n$ and $(1+x)^n$ are,  it follows that $S_n \subseteq S_{nm}$. Let $S= \varinjlim S_{n!}$. This is the set of all non-rational complex numbers $x$ for which there exists an $n$ such that $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are rational.

**Question:** Is $S$ finite?

I have checked with a computer that

$$S_{12}=S_{4!} = S_{5!}=S_{6!}$$
and that $S_n \subseteq S_{12}$ for $n<100$.

**Question** Is $S=S_{12}$? In other words, if $x^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are rational, is it true that $x^{12}$ and $(x+1)^{12}$ are rational?

Micah has remarked in a comment to [David's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1071392/12507) that any $s \in S$ must be a quadratic irrational. So, the finiteness of $S$ would follow if one could prove that finitely many numbers of the form $x(a,b)$ are quadratic irrationals. In order for this to be true, it must be that $x(a,b)^{\sigma^2} = x(a,b)$ for any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q) = (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$. This means that we must have

$$\frac{\zeta^{c^2b}-\zeta^{c^2a}}{1- \zeta^{c^2b}} = \frac{\zeta^b-\zeta^a}{1- \zeta^b}$$
for any $c \in (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$. Perhaps someone can extract an explicit condition on $(a,b)$ from this?...

The set $S_{12}$ consists of $26$ complex numbers. Here is a list of them (here written in terms of a primitive $24$th root of unity $\zeta$):

> $$-1/3\zeta^4 - 1/3$$
>
> $$-1/2\zeta^4 - 1/2$$
>
> $$-2/3\zeta^4 - 2/3$$
>
> $$-\zeta^4 - 1$$
>
> $$-1/2\zeta^6 - 1/2$$
>
> $$-\zeta^6 - 1$$
>
> $$\zeta^4$$
>
> $$-1/2\zeta^4$$
>
> $$-\zeta^4$$
>
> $$-2\zeta^4$$
>
> $$2\zeta^4 - 1$$
>
> $$\zeta^6$$
>
> $$2/3\zeta^4 - 1/3$$
>
> $$-2/3\zeta^4 + 1/3$$
>
> $$-\zeta^6$$
>
> $$-2\zeta^4 + 1$$
>
> $$2\zeta^4 - 2$$
>
> $$z^4 - 1$$
>
> $$1/2\zeta^4 - 1/2$$
>
> $$-\zeta^4 + 1$$
>
> $$\zeta^6 - 1$$
>
> $$1/2\zeta^6 - 1/2$$
>
> $$\zeta^4 - 2$$
>
> $$2/3\zeta^4 - 4/3$$
>
> $$1/2\zeta^4 -1$$
>
> $$1/3\zeta^4 - 2/3$$

Here is where they lie in the complex plane:

[image]

Here is a brief preview of the behavior of the function $f(n):=\#S_n$, as a plot of $f(n)$ for $n=2$ to $n=100$:

[image]

Comment: How about $x^n$ and $(x+a)^n$ for some integer $a$?

Comment: You included some rational numbers like $\zeta^6 = -1$ above.Did you mean to exclude them?

Comment: Thanks @Holden, that is a mistake; these numbers are written in terms of a $24$th root of unity.

Comment: @marty My calculations suggest that there are finitely solutions many for any integer $a$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that
$$1 + x = \frac{1 - \zeta^{a}}{1 - \zeta^{b}}.$$
We may  (and do) assume that $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and that $(a,b) = 1$.
We may also assume that $\zeta^a \ne \zeta^b$.

**Claim:** If $x$ has degree at most $2$ over $\mathbf{Q}$, then $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, or $6$.

**Proof:**
Let $E = \mathbf{Q}(x)$, and assume that $[E:\mathbf{Q}] \le 2$.
Since $E$ is abelian (it is contained in a cyclotomic field), the complex conjugate of $x$ also lies in $E$.
The complex conjugate is obtained by
 replacing $\zeta$ by $\zeta^{-1}$.
Hence the ratio
$$\frac{1+x}{ 1+\overline{x}} = \zeta^{a - b}$$
also lies in $E$. Let $\alpha = \zeta^{a-b} \ne 1$.
Then, solving for $\zeta^b$ in the equation
$$1 + x = \frac{1 - \alpha \cdot \zeta^b}{1 - \zeta^b},$$
we find that
$$\zeta^b = \frac{x}{1 + x - \alpha} \in E.$$
It follows that $\zeta^b $ and $\zeta^a = \alpha \cdot \zeta^b$ both lie in $E$, and hence 
that $\zeta \in E$. In particular, the degree of the field $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ is at most $2$, from
which it follows that $n$ is one of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, or $6$.

More generally, if one assumes that $x$ generates a field of degree $m$, then one
can deduce in the same way that $\varphi(n) \le m$, where $\varphi(n) = [\mathbf{Q}(\zeta):\mathbf{Q}]$
is the Euler $\varphi$ function.