# $S_n$ is an integer for all integers $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ be a non-zero real number. For each integer $n$, we define $S_n = a^n + a^{-n}$. Prove that if for some integer $k$, the sums $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ are integers, then the sums $S_n$ are integers for all integers $n$.

We have $S_{k} = a^k+\frac{1}{a^k} = m_1$ and $S_{k+1} = a^{k+1}+\frac{1}{a^{k+1}} = m_2$ where $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Thus raising $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ to any positive power results in an integer. Is there a way I can prove the statement from this?

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you have proved.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I haven't really proven anything. I just stated a fact.

Comment: No because statement says to generalize for n but you have just written it for some k

Comment: It's not hard to prove if $a+a^{-1}$ is integer then $a^n+a^{-n}$ is integer.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar And that's what the question says: the sums $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ are integers. I didn't say I solved the question.

Comment: But $a^n+a^{-n}$ are integers only for $0,1,\infty$ so I don't it's true

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $a$ doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: I suspect that [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069786/a-real-number-x-such-that-xn-and-x1n-are-rational-is-itself-rational) might be somehow related. It also runs into the issue of being false for complex numbers, but true for real numbers. However, the connection is surely not obvious to me. EDIT: Actually, if one plugs in a the polynomial relating $x+x^{-1}$ to $x^n+x^{-n}$ into the accepted answer there, I wonder if something good falls out.

Answer (score 6):

It's not true if $a$ is allowed to be complex.  For example, if $a$ is a root of $z^4 - z^2 + 1$ we have $a^2 + a^{-2} = 1$ and $a^3 + a^{-3} = 0$ but $a + a^{-1} = \pm \sqrt{3}$.

EDIT:  Using the symmetries $a \to 1/a$ (leaving $S_k$ invariant) and $a \to -a$ (with $S_k \to (-1)^k S_k$), we  may assume $a \ge 1$.  Of course if $a = 1$, all $S_k = 2$ are integers, so we're reduced to the case $a > 1$.  Moreover we may assume $n > 1$, since if $a + 1/a$ is an integer so are all $a^k + 1/a^k$. Of course all $S_k > 0$.

Consider the polynomials $P(z) = z^{2n} - S_n z^n + 1$ and $Q(z) = z^{2n+2} - S_{n+1} z^{n+1} + 1$.   $a$ is a root of both of these.  In particular it is an algebraic integer.  But if $a$ is rational, it must be an integer, and then (since $a > 1$) it would be impossible to have $S_n$ an integer.

Now both $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are multiples of the minimal polynomial $M(z)$ of $a$, which is at least quadratic.
 If $z$ is a root of $P(z)$, then so is $\omega z$ where $\omega$ is any $n$'th root of $1$.  Thus the roots of $P(z)$ are $a \omega$ and $a^{-1} \omega$ for the $n$'th roots $\omega$ of $1$.  Similarly, the roots of $Q(z)$ are $a \zeta$ and $a^{-1} \zeta$ for the $n+1$'th roots $\zeta$ of $1$.  But except for $1$, an $n$'th root of $1$ is not an $n+1$'th root of $1$, so the common roots of $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are $a$ and $1/a$.  Thus these are the only possible roots of $M(z)$, and $M(z)$ is quadratic: in fact $M(z) = (z-a)(z-1/a)$, and thus $S_1 = a + 1/a$ must be an integer.

Comment: This is interesting, but not an answer per se.

Comment: True, but it constrains the possible answers.  You need to use the fact that $a$ is real.

Comment: ... and now I have an answer.

Comment: Well done! ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Partial stuff:

Lemma: If $b+b^{-1}$ is an integer then $b^n+b^{-n}$ is an integer for all $n$.

The proof is via induction.

Notice that by Newton's theorem (and symmetry of binomial coefficients) $(b+b^{-1})^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{i}(b^ib^{-(n-i)}+b^{n-i}{b^{-i}})+A$ (where $A=0$ if $n$ is odd and $A=\binom{n}{n/2}$ otherwise).

Notice every summand except for $b^n+b^{-n}$ is an integer by the inductive hypothesis, and $(b+b^{-1})^n$ is also an integer. We conclude $b^n+b^{-n}$ i an integer.

---

Setting $b=a^k$ and $a^{k+1}$ we have $a^{nk}+a^{-nk}$ and $a^{n(k+1)}+a^{-n(k+1)}$ are integers for all $n$.

---

Solution: Let $T_n$ be the polynomial defined by $T_0(x)=2,T_1(x)=x,T_{n+1}=xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$. We then have $T_n(a+a^{-1})=a^n+a^{-n}$, it follows from the recursion  that if two consecutive values $T_k(x),T_{k+1}(x)$ are integer then $T_n(x)$ is an integer for all $x$.

Comment: That last bit is going to need some more explanation, especially in light of Robert's answer

Comment: yeah, I'm a bit lot to be honest.

Comment: In fact the "solution" seems to only be the fact $S_{n+1}=S_1S_n-S_{n-1}$

Comment: Perhaps it is notable that
$$
(S_k)^2 = S_0 + S_{2k}
$$

Comment: I think this is wrong. $A=-\binom{n}{n/2}a^{\frac{n}{2}}a^{-\frac{n}{2}}$ otherwise?

Comment: Yeah, the last part is wrong.

Comment: Is the proof of your lemma wrong?

Comment: No, notice $a^{n/2}a^{-n/2}=1$.

Comment: I think it should be minus.

Comment: No, I think it is okay as plus. Either way the rest of the proof would follow unchanged :)

Comment: Notice that if $n$ is odd then we only sum for $i=1,2,3,\dots (n-1)/2$. So we need to add the other summand.

Comment: But you say $A = 0$ if $n$ is odd. Is that a mistake?

Comment: You're right, it should be ok now. Thanks for seeing that.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the proof of the lemma: Notice every summand except for $b^n+b^{-n}$ is an integer by the inductive hypothesis, and $(b+b^{-1})^n$ is also an integer. We conclude $b^n+b^{-n}$ i an integer. What was the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: the inductive hypothesis is that $b^k+b^{-k}$ is an integer for $k<n$. It is by strong induction.

Comment: Your last statement is only true for $x$ an integer. However, that is exactly what is to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Result:** For any integers $p,q$, we have
$$
S_p S_q = (a^p + a^{-p})(a^{q} + a^{-q}) = 
(a^{p+q} + a^{-(p+q)}) + (a^{p-q} + a^{-(p-q)}) =
S_{p+q} + S_{p-q}
$$
and conversely, whenever $x$ and $y$ are either both odd or both even with $x > y$, we have
$$
S_{x} + S_y = S_{(x+y)/2}S_{(x-y)/2}
$$
If $q = (2k + 1)p$, we have
$$
\frac{S_q}{S_p} = \sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-1)^i a^{2(k-i)p} = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^kS_{ip} 
$$

Comment: How do we solve the question with this?

Comment: Not sure yet. ${}$