# $F$ is a field and $\alpha$ is any element. Then $[F(\alpha) :F(\alpha^3)]=1 \mbox{ or } 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be any field.

I have tried to find $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^3)]$.

First, $x^3 - \alpha^3 $ is polynomial over $F(\alpha^3)$ having zero $\alpha$.

So $\mathrm{irr}(\alpha,F(\alpha^3)$ divides $x^3-\alpha^3$.

So $\deg(\alpha,F(\alpha^3))$ is 1,2, or 3.

> Claim : $\deg(\alpha,F(\alpha^3)) \;|\; 3$, that is, $\deg(\alpha,F(\alpha^3)\neq 2$.

Could you help me?

Comment: What is $deg (\alpha,(F\alpha^3))$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @heptagon $deg(\alpha, F(\alpha^3)) = \mbox{ degree of $irr(\alpha,F(\alpha^3)$}.$

Comment: I do not understand what is $irr (\alpha,(F\alpha^3))$ either.

Comment: $irr(\alpha, F(\alpha^3) $ is minimal monic polynomial in $F(\alpha)[x]$ having zero $\alpha$.

Comment: Do see [this result](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/133581/11619) for a correct version of this claim. My counterexample is based on the trick that I arranged $\alpha^3$ to be a cube **of a number other than $\alpha$** in the field $F(\alpha^3)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Let's denote $\beta=\root3\of2$, $F=\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\alpha=\omega\root3\of2$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. We then have $\alpha\notin F(\alpha^3)=F\subset\Bbb{R}$, and $\alpha^3=2\in F$. But 
$$\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2=\frac{\alpha^3-\beta^3}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{2-2}{\alpha-\beta}=0.$$
Therefore $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial
$$
m(x)=x^2+\beta x+\beta^2\in F[x]\subseteq F(\alpha^3)[x].
$$
Hence
$$
[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^3)]=2
$$
in this case.

Comment: Simpler example: $\omega^3 \in \mathbb Q$, but $\omega$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: LOL. A good one, @DustanLevenstein! My autopilot was dead set to use the fact that $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$ are not linearly disjoint over their intersection.