# Find $[\mathbb{Q}({5}^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and the minimal polynomial of a over Q.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I have tried doing this by splitting fields and then using the tower law but I have not had any luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Question:
Find $[\mathbb{Q}({5}^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and the minimal polynomial of a over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It is $f(x)=x^4-5$, and the degree is $4$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133581/when-is-xn-a-is-irreducible-over-f).

Comment: Presumably, $a$ is $5^{1/4}?$

Comment: Is it possible to show this by splitting field and tower law? As I do not understand the question linked. Thanks

Comment: Presumably you want to exhibit the extension$\Bbb Q(5^{1/4})\supset\Bbb Q$ as a tower of two quadratic extensions. The only intermediate extension is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$.

Answer (score 0):

$5^{1/4}$ satisfies $x^4-5$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion. So it is the minimal polynomial of $5^{1/4}$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]=\deg{x^4-5}=4$. So the degree of the extension is $4$.