# When does $x^n-n$ factor?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $n=(kj)^k$ for some integers $j\geq 1$ and $k\geq 2$. Then writing $m=k^{k-1}j^k$, we have
$$x^n-n=(x^m)^k - (kj)^k$$ and so $x^m-kj$ is a factor of $x^n-n$. I would like to show that this is the only way that $x^n-n$ can factor over the integers, that is, if $x^n-n$ is not irreducible, then $n=(kj)^k$ for some positive integers $j,k$, with $k\geq 2$.

Comment: Hi Math 101: I am fear that $5^3-3$ does not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Yes, it should be $k\geq 2$. I made the correction. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Math 101: $a^c-b^c$ is always trivially factored. If your $a^c-c$ is always a prime when $c$ is not a power then CONGRATULATIONS. I am convinced this is not true, I am sorry.

Comment: Hmm, so for example $x^5 - 5$ is irreducible by Eisenstein.  And then, $x^{25} - 25$ should be irreducible because there is a valuation on $\mathbb{Q}(5^{2/25})$ extending the 5-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $5^{2/25}$ has valuation $\frac{2}{25}$, which makes it impossible for $5^{2/25}$ to be a root of any polynomial with integer coefficients of degree less than 25 (since the terms of the expansion which have lowest valuation would have no way to cancel out).

Comment: Piquito: I am not sure I follow your reasoning. For example x^2-2 is irreducible but 7^2-2 is prime and 11^2-2 is not. How would knowing that x^c-c is irreducible allow us to conclude something about a^c-c being or not being a prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit too large for a comment, but rules out many cases as irreducible. It gives a necessary but not sufficient condition $n$ must satisfy.

Here is the lemma we prove: if for any $p$ dividing $n$ we have that $\gcd(v_p(n), n)=1$, then the polynomial for $n$ is irreducible. Here, $v_p(n)$ is the p-adic valuation of $n$.

We look at the Newton polygons for every prime $p$ that divides $n$. Specifically, they are all pure of slope $-\frac{v_p(n)}{n}$. If for at least one $p$ dividing $n$ we have that $\gcd(v_p(n), n)=1$ then this implies that it is irreducible because the Newton polygon does not pass through an integer point meaning it can't factor into two polynomials.

This means if it is reducible, we must have that $\gcd(v_p(n), n)>1$ for all $p$ dividing $n$. So we can write $v_p(n)=p*k_p$ for some integer $k_p\ge 1$, and we have,

$$n=\prod_{p |n} p^{pk_p}$$

Unfortunately this isn't enough to prove your factorization must occur, but it does open the door to trying to brute force search for a counterexample to the conjecture.

Comment: I don't have time to amend the answer this moment, but it seems as though the problem can be solved conclusively using this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133598/741168

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that answer, it does look like my question can be answered and I plan to look at the book by Karpilovsky.