# Different approach to see that $X^{nm}-2^n3^m$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I came across the problem to show that when $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ are coprime then the polynomial $X^{nm}-2^n3^m$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. I solved it appealing to knowledge of complex numbers, that is, showing that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of such polynomial then $|\alpha |=2^{1/m}3^{1/n}$ and after showing that $|\alpha |^k\notin \mathbb{Z}$ for any $k\in\{1,\ldots,nm-1\}$, what makes impossible to write such polynomial as the product of two polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

However I suppose that there must be a more elegant argument using some number theory and some irreducibility criterion as reducing the polynomial to some $\mathbb{Z}_p$ field for appropiate prime $p$. Anyway Im just supposing that such argument must exists.

To resume, I opened this question to see if someone have a more purely algebraic or number theoretic argument to show the irreducibility of such polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: in general , it is far from trivial to show that some polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Eisenstein deos here only work if $m=1$ or $n=1$. I doubt that there is something better than the proof you have shown.

Comment: @Peter thank you for your comment, I'm starting to learn field theory so I suppose that there must exists other arguments.

Comment: This is a special case of [When is $X^n-a$ is irreducible over F?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133581)

Comment: @Sil But the linked question is about irreducibility over a field. Here we care about irreducibility over a ring.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos By Gauss lemma irreducibility is equivalent to irreducibility over rationals which is a field

Comment: The polynomial is primitive (coprime coefficients) , hence irreducibility over $\mathbb Z[x]$ implies irreducibility over $\mathbb Q[x]$